# Replace NAs in one column with values from another when all values are dates

Tags: r, date, replace

How can I replace `NA`s in one column with values from another column (when all values are dates)? I can do it with numbers, but for date values when I try

```
mydata$enddate <- ifelse(!is.na(mydata$End.date.html), 
                         mydata$End.date1, 
                         mydata$End.date2)
```

it changes all dates to unrelated numbers. I am sure there is a way to replace missing dates.

Comment: `ifelse` strips attributes. This is converting your date format to numeric. You will need to convert it back. An example of data would be helpful.

Comment: `dplyr::coalesce` is built for this purpose and handles dates properly, e.g. `dplyr::coalesce(c(Sys.Date(), NA), Sys.Date())`

Comment: I tried is.Date to convert it back, but it needs an "origin" to covert the dates based on that. Which I am not sure what that origin would be. I tried the date that was changed to "1" as origin, but it produced unrelated dates some were 2056!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is just to store which values in the column are NA, and then use that vector to query the second column and assign those values back to the first column, like so:

```
invalid.dates <- is.na(mydata$datecol1)

if(any(invalid.dates)) {
   mydata$datecol1[invalid.dates] <- mydata$datecol2[invalid.dates]
}
```

Comment: This is how you do this. You can drop the wrapping `if` statements, if you want, but when you are imputing based on another column in the same data, you already have a structure that allows you to extract and assign exactly the values you want.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the `ifelse` documentation  (`?ifelse`) examples:

```
> ## ifelse() strips attributes
> ## This is important when working with Dates and factors
> x <- seq(as.Date("2000-02-29"), as.Date("2004-10-04"), by = "1 month")
> head(x)
[1] "2000-02-29" "2000-03-29" "2000-04-29" "2000-05-29" "2000-06-29" "2000-07-29"
> ## has many "yyyy-mm-29", but a few "yyyy-03-01" in the non-leap years
> y <- ifelse(as.POSIXlt(x)$mday == 29, x, NA)
> head(y) # not what you expected ... ==> need restore the class attribute:
[1] 11016 11045 11076 11106 11137 11167
> class(y) <- class(x)
> head(y)
[1] "2000-02-29" "2000-03-29" "2000-04-29" "2000-05-29" "2000-06-29" "2000-07-29"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would drop the `ifelse` altogether:

```
mydata$enddate<-mydata$End.date1
mydata$enddate[is.na(mydata$End.date1)]<-mydata$End.Date2[is.na(mydata$End.date1)]
```

Comment: That's @Daniel 's solution below.

Comment: @DanHall close, but mine does away with the superfluous `if`. Also, @Daniel 's solution ignores the bit where NAs in End.Date1 get replaced with data from End.Date2 in *a third column* called enddate.